# How to convert a whole dataset column from text data to binay data in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi guys I am working on a machine learning project but I am stuck up with converting a whole dataset column from text data to binary data in matlab.

For example if the column contains description of what type of website it is like:

```
art_entertainment
culture_politics
recreation 
computer_internet
science_technology
health 
religion
```

So in above example there are seven different types right each one should be represented in binary in this way:

```
art_entertainment: 0000001
culture_politics: 0000010
recreation :0000100
computer_internet: 0001000
science_technology: 0010000
health: 0100000
religion: 1000000
```

I need a matlab code for this please if anybody can help me out

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you want to do. You want to read a bunch of strings and map each string to a binary number? Are those numbers already known or you need to add a new number each time you find a new string? Or are those options you listed the only possible strings and numbers?

Comment: yes i want to read bunch of strings and map each string to a binary number. No those numbers are not given. We have to insert as the loop goes on. If same string appears in loop it has to insert same binary number. I just gave it as a example that it should be in that way. what i meant by that example is if art_entertainment given 0000001 then the next following string should be given 0000010.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your input strings on a cell array like this:

```
strings = {
    'art_entertainment'
    'culture_politics'
    'recreation'
    'computer_internet'
    'science_technology'
    'health'
    'religion'
};
```

Then you could do it like this:

```
bins = dec2bin(cellfun(@(string) find(strcmp(string, unique(strings, 'stable')), 1, 'first'), strings), 8);
```

This would be the result:

```
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000100
00000101
00000110
00000111
```

It also works if you have duplicate entries, where the first binary number will be used. For example, if the strings are:

```
strings = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'a' 'b'};
```

The result would be:

```
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000001
00000010
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to read strings from a column in a dataset and if the same string repeats it needs to be ignored. i have the dataset in .mat format for example train.mat format so can you please tell me how to do it. i am new to matlab please dont mind.

Comment: After doing as i said above i want all the binary in a column and in the same place where their respect strings where there in the column